# How to get out put from a TOP terminal command using Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to retrieve CPU usage of system using

```
top -F -R -o cpu
```

The command is running fine in terminal however I am not able to get the output in Objective c using the code given below:

```
-(NSString*)runCommand:(NSString*)commandToRun;
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                          nil];
    NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;
}
```

I am getting the empty string as a result.

Please suggest what should I do. Many thanks.

Comment: ’commandToRun’ might be an array of strings because you have to pass command and arguments separately. And add a pipe for `stderr` to get potential errors.

Comment: will using `ps -vaA` instead of `top` satisfy your requirement, not sure how top would return data as it's updating each second

Comment: @vadian not if you use `-c`, the command should be a single string

Comment: @Wain I didn't know that, thanks, I've never used -c

Comment: Thanks @Wain `ps -vaA` is really satisfying. Many thanks. However it would be great if we could know why did not we get output from *TOP* commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried using `top` before in this way, I suspect the issue is related to top updating the output every second. In that case you could try a different `top` command:

```
top -F -R -o cpu -l 1
```

or use a different tool to get the data you want, like `ps`:

```
ps -vaA
```

Comment: `Error opening terminal: unknown.` This is the error that I was getting.